# from which file grep found match

Tags: linux, unix, grep

when doing something like this:

```
cat *.* | grep mystring
```

is it possible to know from which file each match comes from? If not what would be the alternative?

Comment: Alternative: `grep mystring *.*`

Comment: What do you mean by "something like"? For your example `grep -H mystring *.*` works perfectly adequately (`-H` in case `*.*` matches only one file).

Comment: Note that `cat` has no option to display file names, so once you have entered `cat *.*` there can be no way to show file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [grep -l](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html):

`-l, --files-with-matches
        Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from
        which output would normally have been printed.`

E.g.

`$ echo foo > file1
 $ echo bar > file2
 $ grep -l foo *
 file1`

Or with line numbers *where* the string occured:

`$ grep -rn foo .
file1:1:foo`